# Modificar entrada de datos Java Array

Tags: java, array

tengo este programilla que hace un cálculo de los escaños para las elecciones de la comunidad autónoma de Galicia, el programa es sencillo y se centra exclusivamente en las 5 partidos más votados. Se pide que el programa calcule los datos provincia a provincia y luego haga el calculo total ordenándolo de mayor a menos en número de diputados. Mi problema viene cuando quiero modificarlo para que las 3 primeras provincias las calcule automitacamente con datos previamente añadidos (son datos reales de las pasadas elecciones) y necesito dejar la última provincia para que sean añadidos manualmente. Me he atascado y no soy capaz de avanzar más.

Si alguien con un corazón enorme me puede ayudar le estaré eternamente agradecido.

Muchísimas gracias.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    int c, p, cont, n, pos_maximo_c, pos_maximo_p, aux, resto_max, resto_aux, op, votantes, censo = 600000, censogal=2400000;
    int escano, prov, votostotales = 0;
    float max, abstencion, abstenciongal=0;
    String provincia[] = {"A Coruña", "Lugo", "Ourense", "Pontevedra"};
    String partido[] = {"BNG", "Ciudadanos", "PP", "PSOE", "En Marea"};
    //String presidentes [] {"Ana Ponton", "Fran Hervía", "Alberto Núñez-Feijoo", "Gonzalo Caballero", "Anton Gómez-Reino"};
    int votos_coruna[]={51043, 19248, 276223, 99263, 11866};
    int votos_lugo[]={13543,5062,96728,34811,28125};
    int votos_ourense[]={10500,4797,92148,30672,24005};
    int votos[] = new int[5];
    float hondt[][];
    int diputados[][] = new int[4][5];
    int totalpartidos[] = new int[5];
    int votosgalicia[] = new int[4];


    do {

        escano = 0;
        prov = 0;
        cont = 1;
        n = 2;
        votantes = 0;
        abstencion = 0;

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("1 - Elecciones en la provincia de A Coruña");
        System.out.println("2 - Elecciones en la provincia de Lugo");
        System.out.println("3 - Elecciones en la provincia de Ourense");
        System.out.println("4 - Elecciones en la provincia de Pontevedra");
        System.out.println("5 - Elecciones en toda Galicia");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.print("Seleccione una de las opciones: ");
        op = entrada.nextInt();

        switch (op) {

            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:

                if (op == 1) {
                    escano = 25;
                    prov = 0;
                }

                if (op == 2) {
                    escano = 14;
                    prov = 1;
                }

                if (op == 3) {
                    escano = 22;
                    prov = 2;
                }

                if (op == 4) {
                    escano = 14;
                    prov = 3;

                }

                hondt = new float[escano][5];

                for (p = 0; p < 5; p++) {                   //Metemos el numero de votos en el array de partidos
                    System.out.println("Introduce el número de votos para el " + partido[p] + ": ");
                    votos[p] = entrada.nextInt();
                    votantes = votos[p] + votantes;

                }
                votosgalicia[prov] = votantes;

                if (votantes > 600000) {
                    System.out.println("*************");
                    System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error en el recuento de votos. Hay más votos que personas censadas.");
                    System.out.println("*************");
                } else {
                    abstencion = ((float) (censo - votantes) / (float) censo) * (float) 100;

                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("*************");
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("El número total de votos para la provincia de " + provincia[op - 1] + " ha sido de: " + votantes);
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("*************");
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("La abstención en la provincia de " + provincia[op - 1] + " ha sido del: " + abstencion + "%");
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("*************");

                    for (p = 0; p < 5; p++) {                   //Metemos el num votos en la primera fila de hondt
                        hondt[0][p] = votos[p];
                    }

                    for (c = 1; c < escano; c++) {                  //Haciendo cocientes y meterlos en la tabla
                        for (p = 0; p < 5; p++) {
                            hondt[c][p] = (hondt[c - cont][p]) / n;
                        }
                        cont++;
                        n++;
                    }

                    for (p = 0; p < 5; p++) {                 
                        System.out.println("*************");
                        for (c = 0; c < escano; c++) {
                            System.out.print((float) hondt[c][p] + " ");
                        }
                    }

                    // buscar   18 veces  el maximo
                    for (int veces = 0; veces < escano; veces++) {

                        max = hondt[0][0];                        //Reset al maximo cuando termino un cociente,
                        pos_maximo_c = 0;
                        pos_maximo_p = 0;

                        for (c = 0; c < escano; c++) {

                            for (p = 0; p < 5; p++) {
                                if (hondt[c][p] > max) {
                                    max = hondt[c][p];

                                    pos_maximo_c = c;
                                    pos_maximo_p = p;

                                }
                            }
                        }

                        diputados[prov][pos_maximo_p]++;             //Despues de tener el máximo de toda la tabla
                        hondt[pos_maximo_c][pos_maximo_p] = 0;
                    }

                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println(" ");

                    System.out.println("Las elecciones en la provincia de: " + provincia[(op - 1)] + " han tenido el siguiente resultado: ");
                    for (p = 0; p < 5; p++) {

                        if (hondt[0][p] == censo * 0.05) {               //Si el partido consigue igual o menos del 5% de votos no entra
                            System.out.println(partido[p] + ": no entra en el parlamento");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println(partido[p] + ": " + diputados[prov][p]);
                        }

                    }

                }
                break;

            case 5:
                System.out.println();
                for (prov = 0; prov < 4; prov++) {
                    System.out.println("Diputados por la provincia de :" + provincia[prov]);
                    for (p = 0; p < 5; p++) {

                        System.out.println(partido[p] + ": " + diputados[prov][p]);



                    }
                    System.out.println("###################");

                }

                int s = 0;
                for (prov = 0; prov < 4; prov++) {

                    s = votosgalicia[prov] + s;
                    abstenciongal = ((float) (censogal - s) /  (float)censogal) * (float) 100;
                }


                System.out.println("El total de votos en Galiza fue de: " + s);
                System.out.println("El total abstenciones en Galiza fue de: " +abstenciongal);
                break;

        }

    } while (op != 0);

}
```

}

Comment: Deberías cambiar la información que muestras e incluir un código similar pero sin información personal como los nombres de otras personas, y ¿este código será usado por algún gobierno? ya que podría haber regulaciones que debas seguir

Comment: Hola, es un trabajo de clase basado en las elecciones autonómicas de 2016 en Galicia, España, son todo datos de carácter público y que puedes consultar en la hemeroteca de cualquier diario español. Los nombres que figuran son los secretarios generales de cada uno de estos partidos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mi problema viene cuando quiero modificarlo para que las 3 primeras
>   provincias las calcule automitacamente con datos previamente añadidos

Con lo anterior te refieres a que si estos valores no son definidos tome los valores de los array que estan definidos como:

```
int votos_coruna[]={51043, 19248, 276223, 99263, 11866};
int votos_lugo[]={13543,5062,96728,34811,28125};
int votos_ourense[]={10500,4797,92148,30672,24005};
```

para esto debes revisar si la provincia no tuvo votos en todos sus partidos, de esta forma determinarías que no se introdujeron y procedes a llenar el array con los predeterminados de los array anteriormente mencionados, lo realizarías de esta forma:

```
     case 5:
            System.out.println();
            for (prov = 0; prov < 4; prov++) {
                System.out.println("Diputados por la provincia de :" + provincia[prov]);


                /*-------Verifica si no se introdujeron valores los calcule automáticamente--------------------*/
                //Revisa si valore de primeras provincias estan vacios.
                if(provincia[prov].equals("A Coruña")){                       
                    if(diputados[prov][0] == 0 && diputados[prov][1] == 0 && diputados[prov][2] == 0 && diputados[prov][3] == 0){                               
                            //Lleva con valores pretederminados.
                            for (p = 0; p < 5; p++) {
                                 diputados[prov][p] = votos_coruna[p];
                             }
                    }
                }else if(provincia[prov].equals("Lugo")){
                    if(diputados[prov][0] == 0 && diputados[prov][1] == 0 && diputados[prov][2] == 0 && diputados[prov][3] == 0){
                            //Lleva con valores pretederminados.
                            for (p = 0; p < 5; p++) {
                                 diputados[prov][p] = votos_lugo[p];
                             }
                    }
                }else if(provincia[prov].equals("Ourense")){ 
                    if(diputados[prov][0] == 0 && diputados[prov][1] == 0 && diputados[prov][2] == 0 && diputados[prov][3] == 0){
                           //Lleva con valores pretederminados.
                           for (p = 0; p < 5; p++) {
                               diputados[prov][p] = votos_ourense[p];
                           }
                    }
                }
                /*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

                for (p = 0; p < 5; p++) {
                    System.out.println(partido[p] + ": " + diputados[prov][p]);
                }
                System.out.println("###################");

            }

            int s = 0;
            for (prov = 0; prov < 4; prov++) {

                s = votosgalicia[prov] + s;
                abstenciongal = ((float) (censogal - s) /  (float)censogal) * (float) 100;
            }


            System.out.println("El total de votos en Galiza fue de: " + s);
            System.out.println("El total abstenciones en Galiza fue de: " +abstenciongal);
            break;

    }
```

---

Este sería el código completo:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    int c, p, cont, n, pos_maximo_c, pos_maximo_p, aux, resto_max, resto_aux, op, votantes, censo = 600000, censogal=2400000;
    int escano, prov, votostotales = 0;
    float max, abstencion, abstenciongal=0;
    String provincia[] = {"A Coruña", "Lugo", "Ourense", "Pontevedra"};
    String partido[] = {"BNG", "Ciudadanos", "PP", "PSOE", "En Marea"};
    //String presidentes [] {"Ana Ponton", "Fran Hervía", "Alberto Núñez-Feijoo", "Gonzalo Caballero", "Anton Gómez-Reino"};
    int votos_coruna[]={51043, 19248, 276223, 99263, 11866};
    int votos_lugo[]={13543,5062,96728,34811,28125};
    int votos_ourense[]={10500,4797,92148,30672,24005};
    int votos[] = new int[5];
    float hondt[][];
    int diputados[][] = new int[4][5];
    int totalpartidos[] = new int[5];
    int votosgalicia[] = new int[4];


    do {

        escano = 0;
        prov = 0;
        cont = 1;
        n = 2;
        votantes = 0;
        abstencion = 0;

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("1 - Elecciones en la provincia de A Coruña");
        System.out.println("2 - Elecciones en la provincia de Lugo");
        System.out.println("3 - Elecciones en la provincia de Ourense");
        System.out.println("4 - Elecciones en la provincia de Pontevedra");
        System.out.println("5 - Elecciones en toda Galicia");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.print("Seleccione una de las opciones: ");
        op = entrada.nextInt();

        switch (op) {

            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:

                if (op == 1) {
                    escano = 25;
                    prov = 0;
                }

                if (op == 2) {
                    escano = 14;
                    prov = 1;
                }

                if (op == 3) {
                    escano = 22;
                    prov = 2;
                }

                if (op == 4) {
                    escano = 14;
                    prov = 3;

                }

                hondt = new float[escano][5];

                for (p = 0; p < 5; p++) {                   //Metemos el numero de votos en el array de partidos
                    System.out.println("Introduce el número de votos para el " + partido[p] + ": ");
                    votos[p] = entrada.nextInt();
                    votantes = votos[p] + votantes;

                }
                votosgalicia[prov] = votantes;

                if (votantes > 600000) {
                    System.out.println("*************");
                    System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error en el recuento de votos. Hay más votos que personas censadas.");
                    System.out.println("*************");
                } else {
                    abstencion = ((float) (censo - votantes) / (float) censo) * (float) 100;

                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("*************");
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("El número total de votos para la provincia de " + provincia[op - 1] + " ha sido de: " + votantes);
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("*************");
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("La abstención en la provincia de " + provincia[op - 1] + " ha sido del: " + abstencion + "%");
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("*************");

                    for (p = 0; p < 5; p++) {                   //Metemos el num votos en la primera fila de hondt
                        hondt[0][p] = votos[p];
                    }

                    for (c = 1; c < escano; c++) {                  //Haciendo cocientes y meterlos en la tabla
                        for (p = 0; p < 5; p++) {
                            hondt[c][p] = (hondt[c - cont][p]) / n;
                        }
                        cont++;
                        n++;
                    }

                    for (p = 0; p < 5; p++) {                 
                        System.out.println("*************");
                        for (c = 0; c < escano; c++) {
                            System.out.print((float) hondt[c][p] + " ");
                        }
                    }

                    // buscar   18 veces  el maximo
                    for (int veces = 0; veces < escano; veces++) {

                        max = hondt[0][0];                        //Reset al maximo cuando termino un cociente,
                        pos_maximo_c = 0;
                        pos_maximo_p = 0;

                        for (c = 0; c < escano; c++) {

                            for (p = 0; p < 5; p++) {
                                if (hondt[c][p] > max) {
                                    max = hondt[c][p];

                                    pos_maximo_c = c;
                                    pos_maximo_p = p;

                                }
                            }
                        }

                        diputados[prov][pos_maximo_p]++;             //Despues de tener el máximo de toda la tabla
                        hondt[pos_maximo_c][pos_maximo_p] = 0;
                    }

                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println(" ");

                    System.out.println("Las elecciones en la provincia de: " + provincia[(op - 1)] + " han tenido el siguiente resultado: ");
                    for (p = 0; p < 5; p++) {

                        if (hondt[0][p] == censo * 0.05) {               //Si el partido consigue igual o menos del 5% de votos no entra
                            System.out.println(partido[p] + ": no entra en el parlamento");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println(partido[p] + ": " + diputados[prov][p]);
                        }

                    }

                }
                break;

            case 5:
                System.out.println();
                for (prov = 0; prov < 4; prov++) {
                    System.out.println("Diputados por la provincia de :" + provincia[prov]);


                /*-------Verifica si no se introdujeron valores los calcule automáticamente--------------------*/
                    //Revisa si valore de primeras provincias estan vacios.
                    if(provincia[prov].equals("A Coruña")){                       
                        if(diputados[prov][0] == 0 && diputados[prov][1] == 0 && diputados[prov][2] == 0 && diputados[prov][3] == 0){                               
                                //Lleva con valores pretederminados.
                                for (p = 0; p < 5; p++) {
                                     diputados[prov][p] = votos_coruna[p];
                                 }
                        }
                    }else if(provincia[prov].equals("Lugo")){
                        if(diputados[prov][0] == 0 && diputados[prov][1] == 0 && diputados[prov][2] == 0 && diputados[prov][3] == 0){
                                //Lleva con valores pretederminados.
                                for (p = 0; p < 5; p++) {
                                     diputados[prov][p] = votos_lugo[p];
                                 }
                        }
                    }else if(provincia[prov].equals("Ourense")){ 
                        if(diputados[prov][0] == 0 && diputados[prov][1] == 0 && diputados[prov][2] == 0 && diputados[prov][3] == 0){
                               //Lleva con valores pretederminados.
                               for (p = 0; p < 5; p++) {
                                   diputados[prov][p] = votos_ourense[p];
                               }
                        }
                    }
                    /*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

                    for (p = 0; p < 5; p++) {
                        System.out.println(partido[p] + ": " + diputados[prov][p]);
                    }
                    System.out.println("###################");

                }

                int s = 0;
                for (prov = 0; prov < 4; prov++) {

                    s = votosgalicia[prov] + s;
                    abstenciongal = ((float) (censogal - s) /  (float)censogal) * (float) 100;
                }


                System.out.println("El total de votos en Galiza fue de: " + s);
                System.out.println("El total abstenciones en Galiza fue de: " +abstenciongal);
                break;

        }

    } while (op != 0);

}
```

Comment: Mil millones de gracias! No sabes cuanto te lo puedo agradecer

Comment: Hola @Moucho , me da gusto mi respuesta pudo ayudarte!, esperemos en un futuro puedas compartir tu conocimiento en el sitio ayudando a otros miembros de la comunidad, :-) saludos!